# NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Tags: javascript, firefox, axios, navigator

This error "NS_BINDING_ABORTED" always happens when I try to make large-scale requests in Firefox and I think is the same thing in all the navigators.

I am making a website which reads XLSX files and imports them into the database. Those codes work when I use it in different pieces of HTML.

*Front End Code*

```js
const enviarPlanilha = async () => {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < items.length) {
      Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/pedidos", {
        origem: items[i].ORIGEM,
        pedido: items[i].PEDIDO,
        unidade_carga: items[i].UNIDADE_CARGA,
        unidade: items[i].UNIDADE,
        cliente: items[i].CLIENTE,
        quantidade_pedida: items[i].QUANTIDADE_PEDIDA,
        data_entrega: items[i].DATA_ENTREGA,
        data_embarque: items[i].DATA_EMBARQUE,
        incoterm: items[i].INCOTERM,
        peso: items[i].PESO,
        tipo_unidade_carga: items[i].TIPO_UNIDADE_CARGA,
        largura_uc: items[i].LARGURA_UC,
        comprimento_uc: items[i].COMPRIMENTO_UC,
        altura_uc: items[i].ALTURA_UC,
        produto: items[i].PRODUTO,
      });
      i++;
    }
  };
```

*Back End Code*

```js
router.post("/pedidos", (req, res) => {
  const {
    origem,
    pedido,
    unidade_carga,
    unidade,
    cliente,
    quantidade_pedida,
    data_entrega,
    data_embarque,
    incoterm,
    peso,
    tipo_unidade_carga,
    largura_uc,
    comprimento_uc,
    altura_uc,
    produto,
  } = req.body;

  criarBanco();
  usarBanco();
  criarTablePedidos();

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO pedidos (origem, pedido, unidade_carga, unidade, cliente, quantidade_pedido, data_entrega, data_embarque, incoterm, peso, tipo_unidade_carga, largura_uc, comprimento_uc, altura_uc, produto) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    [
      origem,
      pedido,
      unidade_carga,
      unidade,
      cliente,
      quantidade_pedida,
      data_entrega,
      data_embarque,
      incoterm,
      peso,
      tipo_unidade_carga,
      largura_uc,
      comprimento_uc,
      altura_uc,
      produto,
    ],
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Dados adicionados para a tabela pedidos!");
        res.send("Hello World!");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I am using Firefox (64-bit) 83.0 version. I randomly see ns_binding_aborted on many pages. Sometimes favicon fails to load.

Comment: @Marcelo did you happen to figure this one out?

Comment: @BrunoFrancisco adding event.preventDefault() solved it for me!